# Why links are not working on IDX page?

Tags: wordpress

I am using IDX pages on a website [here](http://ewilkins.webviewconsulting.com/). Link are woking well on the website page. But Menu and sidebar and footer links of website are not working on IDX pages [here](http://homes.propertynorcal.com/idx/contact). Or any other outsider link in Menu and footer not working on IDX pages .

For example I have put a link in the footer on the video icon. AS it is showing well  on hover but not linking on click, it is working fine with open in new tab on right click.

Can anyone where is the problem ? Why these links are not working?

Answer (score 0):

The menus and sidebar links are all woking for me (latest Chrome). Video link at the bottom works correctly for me on click as well as on hover, and right click in a new tab. Since these are IDX Broker pages and not your WP pages you should email their support if this issue is persisting.